# How can I save the result of an SQLDatasource query into a variable in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, sqldatasource

My query result supposedly is a string and I want to save it into a string variable and print it out. But the result is: **System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSource**

using this code: **SQLQueryName.ToString();**

How can I print it out properly?

Answer (score 0):

Get query text by property [System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSource.SelectCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.selectcommand(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: It's not the answer I'm looking for at all, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Try using SQLQueryName.Select(DataSourceSelectArgument.Empty)

See more info on it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.select%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).